# Aligning 2 python lists according to 2 other list

Tags: python

I have two arrays namely **nlxTTL** and **ttlState**. Both the arrays comprise of repeating pattern of 0's and 1's indicating input voltage which can be HIGH(1) or LOW(0) and are recorded from same source which sends a TTL pulse(HIGH and LOW) with 1second pulse width.

But due to some logging mistake, some drops happen in **ttlState** list i.e. it doesn't log a repeating sequence of 0 and 1's and ends up dropping values.

The good part is I also log timestamp for each TTL input received for both the lists. Inter TTL event timestamp difference clearly shows that the TTL event has missed one of the pulses.

Here is an example of what data looks like:

```
nlxTTL, ttlState, nlxTime, ttlTime
0,0,1000,1000
1,1,2000,2000
0,1,3000,4000
1,1,4000,6000
0,0,5000,7000
1,1,6000,8000
0,0,7000,9000
1,1,8000,10000
```

As you can see the **nlxTime** and **ttlTime** clearly are different from each other. How can then using these timestamps I can align all 4 lists?

Comment: why the downvote? It would be good if you can explain so that I can improve question quality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with tabular data such as a CSV file, it's a good idea to use a library to make the process easier. I like the `pandas` dataframe library.

Now for your question, one way to think about this problem is that you really have two datasets... An nlx dataset and a ttl dataset. You want to join those datasets together by timestamp. Pandas makes tasks like this very easy.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data = """\
nlxTTL, ttlState, nlxTime, ttlTime
0,0,1000,1000
1,1,2000,2000
0,1,3000,4000
1,1,4000,6000
0,0,5000,7000
1,1,6000,8000
0,0,7000,9000
1,1,8000,10000
"""

# Load data into dataframe.
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

# Remove spaces from column names.
df.columns = [x.strip() for x in df.columns]

# Split the data into an nlx dataframe and a ttl dataframe.
nlx = df[['nlxTTL', 'nlxTime']].reset_index()
ttl = df[['ttlState', 'ttlTime']].reset_index()

# Merge the dataframes back together based on their timestamps.
# Use an outer join so missing data gets filled with NaNs instead
# of just dropping the rows.
merged_df = nlx.merge(ttl, left_on='nlxTime', right_on='ttlTime', how='outer')

# Get back to the original set of columns
merged_df = merged_df[df.columns]

# Print out the results.
print(merged_df)
```

This produces the following output.

```
   nlxTTL  ttlState  nlxTime  ttlTime
0     0.0       0.0   1000.0   1000.0
1     1.0       1.0   2000.0   2000.0
2     0.0       NaN   3000.0      NaN
3     1.0       1.0   4000.0   4000.0
4     0.0       NaN   5000.0      NaN
5     1.0       1.0   6000.0   6000.0
6     0.0       0.0   7000.0   7000.0
7     1.0       1.0   8000.0   8000.0
8     NaN       0.0      NaN   9000.0
9     NaN       1.0      NaN  10000.0
```

You'll notice that it fills in the dropped values with `NaN` values because we are doing an outer join. If this is undesirable, change the `how='outer'` parameter to `how='inner'` to perform an inner join. This will only keep records for which you have both an nlx and ttl response at that timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I should start learning more about pandas. Although I noticed another condition in the data. I will again use an example to ask it:

 `nlxTTL, ttlState, nlxTime, ttlTime`

 `0,0,1000,10`

 `1,1,2000,20`

 `0,1,3000,40`

 `1,1,4000,60`

 `0,0,5000,70`

 `1,1,6000,80`

 `0,0,7000,90`

 `1,1,8000,100`

How to align the lists if the clocks on nlxTime and ttlTime started with a different time as shown above?

Comment: If this post answered your original question, it's best to wrap up this post. If you have a new problem that you cannot figure out, it would be best to ask it as a new question on StackOverflow so everybody gets a chance to search for it and see it. Before you post a new question, ask yourself what you've tried so far and why those things haven't worked. Then include the examples of what you've tried in your next question.